# How to use categories in the URL with Advanced Custom Fields?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Using the advancedcustomfields.com plugin:

1)I want to post to the ACF and use a category just like a regular blog post, but the URL would be: mysite.com/customPost/category/post-name

Is this possible? And how can I do it?

2)Could I add a custom page template to each category page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1) I dont understand where ACF gets in the picture, for categories and terms you should use custom taxonomies instead of ACF. [Here is a link on how to do that.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies)

2) Yes.  The wowrdpress hierarchy lets you do exactly that. lets say you have taxonomy books, and you want to have different templates for fantasy and romance you can do it like this

```
taxonomy-books-romance.php
taxonomy-books-fantasy.php
```

Its whats called taxonomy-$taxonomy-$term.php in the hierarchy.

[image: Wordpress Hierarchy]

Comment: +1 `I dont understand where ACF gets in the picture` .. And I don´t understand where AFC get´s it´s popularity from :-)